# Python: Best way to break up a large class

Tags: python

I have a very large class which serves as the BaseClass for many AdapterClasses.  The base class consists of methods that can be categorized as follows:

- **translation**: fundamental translation classmethods used by all AdapterClasses. Requires class attributes from AdapterClasses  (used internal / external) The tricky part for this one is i would like to maintain class level access from AdapterClasses, but that eluded me.  Now i have instace level access from AdapterClasses and class level access from Translator directly.
- **operations**: fundamental methods used by all AdapterClasses (internal)
- **adapter methods**: methods that can be overwritten by AdapterClasses for specialized needs. (internal)
- **api methods**: Only used externally, but need access to all internal methods (external)

I was thinking separation as follows would make development a allot easier and make the public api a bit clearer.  Before i take on this re factoring i'd like some feed back. Thoughts, comments, suggestions welcome..

This is an extremely simplified abstraction of what i am doing and is not even close to my actual code.  I Was simply trying to communicate the structure.

One Problem: See comments for class level access to to_adapter.  I would like to access `DislexiaAadpter.tr.to_adapter()` but since it's a class attribute in `Translator` you cant work with multiple adapters simultaneously.  When Translator methods were part of BaseClass this was not an issue.

```
class Translator(object):
    ac = None
    dictionaries = {'english_spanish':{'hello world':'hola mundo', "i'm just backwards":'Solo soy al reves'}}
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.ac = c


    def to_adapter(self, phrase):
        r = self.by_lang(phrase, self.ac.lang)
        return r

    @classmethod
    def by_lang(cls, phrase, lang=None):
        d = cls.get_dictionary(lang)
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for k, v in d.items(): 
                if phrase in k:
                    return v
            return phrase
        else:
            return d

    @classmethod
    def get_dictionary(cls, lang='english'):
        for k, v in cls.dictionaries.items():
            if lang in k:
                k = k.split('_')
                if lang == k[0]:
                    return {v:k for k,v in v.items()}
                else:
                    return v
        return "We don't know that language."


class BaseApi(object):

    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

    def say(self, phrase):
        return self.c.translate(phrase)


class BaseClass(object):
    tr = Translator
    api = BaseApi
    lang = 'english'
    id = 'baseclass'
    slogan = 'base slogan'

    def __init__(self):
        self.tr = Translator(self)
        self.api = self.api(self)

    # operations methods
    def split(self, string):
        l = string.split(':')
        prefix = l[0]
        try:
            phrase = l[1]
        except:
            phrase = prefix
            prefix = ''
        return (phrase, prefix)

    def process_translate(self, phrase, prefix):
        return prefix+': '+phrase if prefix else phrase

    # adapter methods
    def translate(self, phrase):
        phrase, prefix = self.split(phrase)
        phrase = self.tr.to_adapter(phrase)
        return (phrase, prefix)

    def get_slogan(self):
        slogan = self.slogan#self.translate(self.slogan)
        return self.id+"'s slogan is: "+slogan

# AdapterClass
class DislexiaApi(BaseApi):

    def yas(self, phrase):
        hdys = super(DislexiaApi, self).say(phrase)   
        return hdys

class DislexiaClass(BaseClass):
    id = "dislexia"
    lang = 'english'
    slogan = "sdrawkcab tsuj m'i"
    api= DislexiaApi

    def make_dislexic(self, string):
        return string[::-1]

    def translate(self, phrase):
        phrase, prefix = super(DislexiaClass, self).translate(phrase)
        phrase = self.make_dislexic(phrase)
        return self.process_translate(phrase, prefix)


# Wrapper class returns the api of all Adapters. Nice and clean.
class WrapperClass():
    adapters = [DislexiaClass]
    def __init__(self):
        for adapter in self.adapters:
            setattr(self, adapter.id, adapter().api)
```

Usage:

```
# Translator 
print Translator.by_lang('hello world', 'spanish')
hola mundo
print Translator.by_lang('hola mundo', 'english')
hello world

# AdapterClass
d = DislexiaClass()
print d.get_slogan()
dislexia's slogan is: sdrawkcab tsuj m'i
d.translate(slogan)
dislexia's slogan is: i'm just backwards 

# WrapperClass
w = WrapperClass()
wd = w.dislexia
print wd.yas('hello world')
dlrow olleh
print wd.yas('hola mundo')
dlrow olleh
print wd.c.translate(wd.yas('hola mundo'))
hello world
```

Comment: Nice... but are you looking for anything specifc....?  "A design is only as good as it satisfies the requirement"

Comment: python best practices, conventions, clarity, sanity

Comment: This may be a good fit for codereview.SE

Comment: The variable naming could be improved. What is `self.ac`?

Comment: This would indeed be a good fit for Code Review, thanks for mentioning it @AdamSmith

Comment: ac # adapter class. i know the methods are a bit clumsy, i just wanted to communicate the need for segregation of the parts.  The internals of the methods are not my concern as i just wrote it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Phrancis What is Code Review? Ah, found it.  Should i move this over there?

Comment: @arctelix Here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a correct question, but as it is for running code I think it would be better in CodeRiview, according to [this ChrisF's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/3545273) on meta

Comment: How easy was it to 'unit test'? Would it be 'easier' as separate classes?  I have no idea - is just a question. If is one 'entity' then will be fine as just lots of 'routines' that are all related. If different 'entities' in the one class then it may be worthwhile splitting them up. I have no idea.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Not sure what you mean by see some code.  You want to see the actual code vs the simplified code i have in the question?  That would be difficult....

Comment: Hmm, over at code review they did not think it was an appropriate question because it was mock code.  It's hard to get advice on design patterns...

Comment: This question has [already been asked and answered on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79715/9357). It was deemed to be working code, [with the condition that the "not even close to my actual code" caveat be removed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19920905#19920905) from the question first.